# Excel - Dividing total to a range of cells

Tags: excel

I have a issue with my excel project. What I want to do is to divide number of working hours to cells when particular person has a working day. Right now I use QUOTIENT formula with combination with others but the problem is I'm not getting the right split of the total. So set up looks like that

Number of hours = 72
Number of Working days = 7

So I need to divide 72/7 but I need to have the result rounded to full figure (hour). So for example I need day 1 = 10h day 2=12h and day 3 to 7 each = 10h. The QUOTIENT is resulting 10h in every single day giving me result of total 70 not 72.

The problem is that the variables will change when the employee will be switched so for example the next employee will have 94 hours and 11 days. Generally its look like that that I have range of full month so from 1 to 31 and the working days are collected from "working schedule". The idea is to sum up the hours to a month normative working hours. So for example employee has 104 hours and he is working 12 days in working schedule but the monthly norm is 176 so we have 72 hours missing and those hours should be added to those days that he is working.

Example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MOD` function to calculate the remainder.
so day 1 and 3 to 7 should have `=quotient(72,7)`
and day 2 should have `=quotient(72,7)+mod(72,7)`

I suppose from your question that you want the remaining hours to be added to day 2.

Comment: ok, but the problem is that the variables will change when the employee will be switched so for example the next employee will have 94 hours and 11 days. Generally its look like that that I have range of full month so from 1 to 31 and the working days are collected from "working schedule". The idea is to sum up the hours to a month normative working hours. So for example employee has 104 hours and he is working 12 days in working schedule but the monthly norm is 176 so we have 72 hours missing and those hours should be added to those days that he is working.

Comment: You should add these details to the description my editing your question. Perhaps add an example as well so it's easier to understand.